# Show numeric keyboard without letters

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

Is there any option to hide letters under the numbers in the iOS default numeric keyboard?

[image: numeric keyboard with letters]

For some phone languages the keyboard is shown without letters:

[image: keyboard without numbers]

Comment: It looks like the only way is to create your own keyboard view. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243919/how-to-hide-the-letters-on-a-numberpad-keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, what you are asking is impossible. It depends on the keyboard Language and only the user can change the keyboard language.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you please provide some docs that describe this behavior?

Comment: Sir,  doc not always say what is is impossible. Generally doc said only what it's possible. So when you come in stackoverflow you thrust developpers experiences. To do your case you must define your custom keyboard.

Comment: Thanks) Nice philosophic comment