# Hide letters in andoird's numerical keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to hide the letters in the numerical keyboard ?

Just like this guy asked for iOS, but on Android : [Show numeric keyboard without letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938594/show-numeric-keyboard-without-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..,,you can use inputType as number

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" >

</EditText>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Solution 2**

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Comment: I have tried both android:inputType="number" and android:inputType="phone" but there is always 3 letters on the right side of each number. Just like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/2QTO0.png

Comment: @Bencri also please check my updated answer....i hope this may help you

Comment: Is there by any way the possibility to do a mix between the "number" input type and the "phone" input type By that I mean keeping only the 12 keys of the "phone" input type, without the letters (and without the 4 extra keys from the "number" input, which I don't need).

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the input type as number on whatever widget you need it on

```
android:inputType="number"
```