# How to hide the letters on a .numberPad keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uikit

By default, when using a `.numberPad` keyboard on iPhone, the number keys also feature letters at the bottom of each key.

[image]

The letters are purely cosmetic, to help people with number input; but in my case (entering item quantities), they’re completely superfluous, maybe even confusing.

Is it possible to configure the keyboard to hide these letters?
Should I implement my own keyboard view just to properly present the keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t believe there is currently a “digit only” keyboard without the text characters.

But you can create your own:

```
textField.inputView = NumericKeyboard(target: textField)
```

Where

```
class DigitButton: UIButton {
    var digit: Int = 0
}

class NumericKeyboard: UIView {
    weak var target: UIKeyInput?

    var numericButtons: [DigitButton] = (0...9).map {
        let button = DigitButton(type: .system)
        button.digit = $0
        button.setTitle("\($0)", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.accessibilityTraits = [.keyboardKey]
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDigitButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }

    var deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("⌫", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.accessibilityTraits = [.keyboardKey]
        button.accessibilityLabel = "Delete"
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDeleteButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    init(target: UIKeyInput) {
        self.target = target
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: - Actions

extension NumericKeyboard {
    @objc func didTapDigitButton(_ sender: DigitButton) {
        target?.insertText("\(sender.digit)")
    }

    @objc func didTapDeleteButton(_ sender: DigitButton) {
        target?.deleteBackward()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private initial configuration methods

private extension NumericKeyboard {
    func configure() {
        autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addButtons()
    }

    func addButtons() {
        let stackView = createStackView(axis: .vertical)
        stackView.frame = bounds
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(stackView)

        for row in 0 ..< 3 {
            let subStackView = createStackView(axis: .horizontal)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(subStackView)

            for column in 0 ..< 3 {
                subStackView.addArrangedSubview(numericButtons[row * 3 + column + 1])
            }
        }

        let subStackView = createStackView(axis: .horizontal)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(subStackView)

        let blank = UIView()
        blank.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        blank.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor

        subStackView.addArrangedSubview(blank)
        subStackView.addArrangedSubview(numericButtons[0])
        subStackView.addArrangedSubview(deleteButton)
    }

    func createStackView(axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis) -> UIStackView {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = axis
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        return stackView
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Clearly, you can go nuts, customizing your keyboard to look however you’d like to. The above is fairly primitive, something I just dashed together. But it illustrates the idea: Make you own input view and use the `UIKeyInput` protocol to communicate keyboard input to the control.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!
It's a shame that you have to make your own entire view, but at least it looks like it's well-supported by iOS.
Could you comment on how well this does, accessibility-wise?

Comment: Pretty well. You get all the standard free accessibility stuff. (It even recognized “⌫” as “delete”, which I was surprised about. The only thing that’s leaping out at me, accessibility-wise as you say, is to add `button.accessibilityTraits = [.keyboardKey]`, (for example, that enables the “Spoken Content” » “Speak Screen” to speak the keyboard keys, too). But standard VoiceOver works, regardless.